# UAV is the technically correct term

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently, the tag [drones](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drones) has been created. The term drone is a commonly used phrase but is not the technically accurate term which is what should be used on Aviation.SE. [Unmanned aerial vehicle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unmanned_aerial_vehicle) or [uav](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uav) should be created and synonimized with [drones](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drones).

Comment: I definitely agree - my only question is should we distinguish between "UAV" (that which has a pilot playing video games on the ground to control it) and "Autonomous UAV" (that which attempts, usually poorly, to "see and avoid" on its own), or just put them all in the "UAV" bucket?

Comment: @voretaq7 I don't think that Autonomous is necessary, however it could be a good stand-alone tag and you could tag a question with both if needed.

Comment: @lnafziger I'm generally thinking we can lump them all in one bucket (and clarify in the question) myself - but I'll be honest, most of my time thinking about UAVs is occupied with "How can I keep them the heck out of my airspace? New York is complicated and busy enough already!" so I'm certainly not qualified to speculate on them :)

Comment: @voretaq7 In contrast, my main thought these days is how do I get my UAV in the air? :)

Comment: It should be [tag:drone] and not [tag:drones] in plural.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I think that [unmanned-aerial-vehicle](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unmanned-aerial-vehicle) should be used, and since the UAV acronym is so commonly used, a tag synonym should be made for [uav](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uav) as well.

Comment: Currently [uav] and [drone] still exist. Could you tag-synonym them to [unmanned-aerial-vehicle]?

Comment: @raptortech97 Done.

Answer (score 3):

As a side note, law makers are more an more using the acronym "RPAS" (remotely piloted air system). See e.g. the EU official [RPAS webpage](http://ec.europa.eu/enterprise/sectors/aerospace/uas/). Apparently this "remotely piloted" wording is more politically correct than "unmanned".

Comment: [...something-something unMANned KC-10 refueling something something...](http://www.flyingmag.com/news/kc-10-crew-completes-unmanned-aerial-refueling) :-) My question is, are they trying to lead in to a scenario where the aircraft is remotely piloted, but there are actually *people on board the thing*? Crazy lawmakers....

Comment: @voretaq7: given how painful the legal process is for fully-unmanned RPAS, I'm pretty sure we wont be seeing that anytime soon and if we do, it will be most certainly not because of the lawmakers! Pilotless cargo planes are more likely -- FedEx is pushing a lot for that...

Comment: "remotely piloted" is a better catch-all term than "unmanned", especially when you consider RC/hobby aircraft.  somehow, joe blow flying his quadcopter in the park doesn't exactly qualify (in my mind) as "unmanned".

Answer (score 2):

I may have used the [drone](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drone) tag first, and did so because of the common parlance. I wanted early users, especially in public-beta to easily tag things and keep moving / active on the site.

I'll go look to see if the various UAV tags are synonymized correctly with [drone](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drone). If not, I think we are making a mistake until the synonyms are done right.